# Spring not autowiring in unit tests with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit

I test the following DAO with JUnit:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // Other stuff here

}
```

As you can see, the sessionFactory is autowired using Spring. When I run the test, sessionFactory remains null and I get a null pointer exception.

This is the sessionFactory configuration in Spring:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What's wrong? How can I enable autowiring for unit testings too?

Update: I don't know if it's the only way to run JUnit tests, but note that I'm running it in Eclipse with right-clicking on the test file and selecting "run as"->"JUnit test"

Comment: Is `MyDao` included in the scan path?

Comment: What about `<context:annotation-drivern/>`? Do you have it your XMLs?

Comment: I have <tx:annotation-driven /> that is from this namespace  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712707

Answer (score 43):

Add something like this to your root unit test class:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration
```

This will use the XML in your default path. If you need to specify a non-default path then you can supply a locations property to the ContextConfiguration annotation.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html

Comment: I can't see and include these annotations

Comment: Ok I just needed to add something into the pom in order to be able to use the annotation. Now that I added them I get this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers were declared for context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@1dd58d8 declaringClass = 'org.davis.dao.EmployeeDAOImplTest', locations = '{}', classes = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.t...

Comment: Right, add the locations property to your ContextConfiguration annotation and supply the path to your XML file per the spring documentation I gave you.

Comment: I tryed with this, is it correct? @ContextConfiguration(locations={"/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml"})

Comment: I can't tell you if it is correct. For my project I specify it as: locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"

Comment: For me i worked just by adding `@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )` in spring-boot

Comment: @user1883212 for that message see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055876/spring-testing-and-maven

Answer (score 26):

I had same problem with Spring Boot 2.1.1 and JUnit 4
just added those annotations:

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest
```

and all went well.

For Junit 5:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
```

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration)

Comment: Still getting null

Answer (score 25):

I'm using JUnit 5 and for me the problem was that I had imported `Test` from the wrong package:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Replacing it with the following worked for me:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, happened to me now more than once.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the Spring JUnit runner in order to wire in Spring beans from your context. The code below assumes that you have a application context called `testContest.xml` available on the test classpath.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.startsWith;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:**/testContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class someDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testDBSourceIsCorrect() throws SQLException {
        String databaseProductName = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .connection()
                .getMetaData()
                .getDatabaseProductName();
        assertThat("Test container is pointing at the wrong DB.", databaseProductName, startsWith("HSQL"));
    }
}
```

**Note:** This works with *Spring 2.5.2* and *Hibernate 3.6.5*

Comment: The problem is to understand the right path to use. I have my servlet-context.xml under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml and I'm using this location: @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-servlet.xml"})  But this doesn't work. What should I write instead?

Comment: @user1883212 Try `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:**/servlet-context.xml" })`

Comment: @user1883212 using `classpath*:**/<context>.xml` will search for a context anywhere on your classpath. Is you bean defined in your context or in a servlet?

Answer (score 6):

Missing Context file location in configuration can cause this, one approach to solve this:

- Specifying Context file location in ContextConfiguration

like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/your-spring-context.xml" })
```

More details

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/your-spring-context.xml" })
public class UserServiceTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {}
```

Reference:[Thanks to @Xstian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26056103/452708)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add annotations to the Junit class, telling it to use the SpringJunitRunner. The ones you want are:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

This tells Junit to use the test-context.xml file in same directory as your test. This file should be similar to the real context.xml you're using for spring, but pointing to test resources, naturally.