# Test Custom Validator with Autowired spring Service

Tags: spring, validation, testing, hibernate-validator

I have a custom Hibernate Validator for my entities. One of my validators uses an Autowired Spring @Repository. The application works fine and my repository is Autowired successfully on my validator.

The problem is i can't find a way to test my validator, cause i can't inject my repository inside it.

Person.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo", name = "Person")
@PersonNameMustBeUnique
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column()
    @NotBlank()
    private String name;

    //getters and setters
    //...
}
```

PersonNameMustBeUnique.class

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { PersonNameMustBeUniqueValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface PersonNameMustBeUnique{
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends javax.validation.Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The validator:

```
public class PersonNameMustBeUniqueValidatorimplements ConstraintValidator<PersonNameMustBeUnique, Person> {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(PersonNameMustBeUnique constraintAnnotation) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Person entidade, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if ( entidade == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

        boolean isValid = nameMustBeUnique(entidade, context);

        return isValid;
    }

    private boolean nameMustBeUnique(Person entidade, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //CALL REPOSITORY TO CHECK IF THE NAME IS UNIQUE 
        //ADD errors if not unique...
    }
}
```

And the context file has a validator bean:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

Again, it works fine, but i don't know how to test it.

My test file is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

    Person e;
    static Validator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void name__must_not_be_null() {
        e = new Person();
        e.setName(null);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(e);
        assertViolacao(violations, "name", "Name must not be null");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you seen this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714/how-to-write-junit-test-case-with-spring-autowire. Your problem is the test setup not so much anything validator related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On @BeforeClass:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }
```

And in your test you need to replace the beans with your mocked bean:

```
myValidator.initialize(null);
BeanValidatorTestUtils.replaceValidatorInContext(validator, usuarioValidoValidator, e);
```

The class that do all the magic:

```
public class BeanValidatorTestUtils {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static <A extends Annotation, E> void replaceValidatorInContext(Validator validator,
                                                                            final ConstraintValidator<A, ?> validatorInstance,
                                                                                E instanceToBeValidated) {
        final Class<A> anotacaoDoValidador = (Class<A>)
                                                ((ParameterizedType) validatorInstance.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0])
                                                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        ValidationContextBuilder valCtxBuilder = ReflectionTestUtils.<ValidationContextBuilder>invokeMethod(validator,
                                                                                                "getValidationContext");
        ValidationContext<E> validationContext = valCtxBuilder.forValidate(instanceToBeValidated);
        ConstraintValidatorManager constraintValidatorManager = validationContext.getConstraintValidatorManager();

        final ConcurrentHashMap nonSpyHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();
        ConcurrentHashMap spyHashMap = spy(nonSpyHashMap);
        doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object key = invocation.getArguments()[0];
                Object keyAnnotation = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(key, "annotation");
                if (anotacaoDoValidador.isInstance(keyAnnotation)) {
                    return validatorInstance;
                }
                return nonSpyHashMap.get(key);
            }
        }).when(spyHashMap).get(any());

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(constraintValidatorManager, "constraintValidatorCache", spyHashMap);
    }

}
```

Comment: what kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: Reflection baby ;)

Comment: Complex but 1+ for providing solution :)

Comment: please tell in the argument of replaceValidatorInContext, what to pass.

Comment: @ManishBansal the first one is the Validator interface. The second is your custom validator. the third one is the class where the validator will be applied.

Comment: This code no longer works in Hibernate Validator 6.1 because ValidationContext#forValidate now takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Someone solved this problem with newer version of Hibernate?

Answer (score 11):

U can add the following bean to your Spring Context in the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.class)
public class PersonTest {

  @Autowired
  private Validator validator;

  {
    validator.validate(new Person());
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: wow I looked everywhere for something this elegant. pin it to the front page, please.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing very similar problem: How to write pure unit test of custom validator wich has autowired configuration bean?

I could manage to solve it by following code (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57851816/3433612) answer of user [abhishekrvce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907176/abhishekrvce)).

This is pure unit test of custom validator with @Autowired configuration bean, which reads the data from configuration file (not showed in code).

```java
@Import({MyValidator.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfiguration.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
class MyValidatorTest {

  private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @BeforeEach
  void initialize() {
    SpringConstraintValidatorFactory springConstraintValidatorFactory
        = new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setConstraintValidatorFactory(springConstraintValidatorFactory);
    validator.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    validator.afterPropertiesSet();
  }

  @Test
  void isValid()
  {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyObject>> constraintViolations = validator
        .validate(myObjectInstance);
    assertThat(constraintViolations).hasSize(1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Other answers didn't help me in the same situation, this one works, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

We also faced the similar problem where @Autowiring was failing (not initialised) in ConstrainValidator Class. Our ConstraintValidator Implemented class was using a value which supposed to be read from the `application.yml` file.  Below solution helped us as this is using a pure spring scope. Hope this helps, with proper SpringJunit4ClassRunner.

```
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringConstraintValidatorFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.someConfigValue.InApplicationYaml=Value1",
})
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        SpringConstraintValidatorFactory springConstraintValidatorFactory
                    = new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(webApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
            validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
            validator.setConstraintValidatorFactory(springConstraintValidatorFactory);
            validator.setApplicationContext(webApplicationContext);
            validator.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Test
        public void should_have_no_violations_for_all_valid_fields() {

        Set<ConstraintViolation<PojoClassWhichHaveConstraintValidationAnnotation>> violations = validator.validate(pojoClassObjectWhichHaveConstraintValidationAnnotation);

        assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
    }

}


@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Value("${spring.someConfigValue.InApplicationYaml=Value1}")
    public String configValueToBeReadFromApplicationYamlFile;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had the same problem with my custom validator. I needed to validate a model being passed to a controller's method (method level validation). The validator invoked but the dependencies (@Autowired) could not be injected. It took me some days searching and debugging the whole process. Finally, I could make it work. I hope my experience save some time for others with the same problem. Here is my solution:

Having a jsr-303 custom validator like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD,
      ElementType.PARAMETER,
      ElementType.TYPE,
      ElementType.METHOD,
      ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE,
      ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
      ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER,
      ElementType.TYPE_USE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = SampleValidator.class)
public @interface ValidSample {
    String message() default "Default sample validation error";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

public class SampleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidSample, SampleModel> {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService service;


    public void initialize(ValidSample constraintAnnotation) {
    //init
    }

    public boolean isValid(SampleModel sample, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    service.doSomething();
    return true;
    }


}
```

You should configure spring test like this:

```
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "your base packages" })
    @Configurable
    @EnableWebMvc
    class SpringTestConfig {
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
    SpringConstraintValidatorFactory scvf = new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setConstraintValidatorFactory(scvf);
    validator.setApplicationContext(wac);
    validator.afterPropertiesSet();
    return validator;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor mvpp() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor mvpp = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    mvpp.setValidatorFactory((ValidatorFactory) validator());
    return mvpp;
    }

    @Bean
    SampleService sampleService() {
    return Mockito.mock(SampleService.class);
    }

}

@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringTestConfig.class, AnotherConfig.class })
public class ASampleSpringTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;



    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
                 .build();
    }



    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodInvokingCustomValidation(){
         // test implementation
         // for example:
         mockMvc.perform(post("/url/mapped/to/controller")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

}
```

Note that, here I am using testng, but you can use JUnit 4. The whole configuration would be the same except that you would run the test with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and do not extend the AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.

Now, @ValidSample can be used in places mentioned in @Target() of the custom annotation.
**Attention**: If you are going to use the @ValidSample annotation on method level (like validating method arguments), then you should put class level annotation @Validated on the class where its method is using your annotation, for example on a controller or on a service class.

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but I have the impression your tests completely ignores that validator, because you don't set any validator in MockMvc. eg:
 MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(getTestInstance())
                .setValidator(new LocalValidatorFactoryBean())
                .build();

Comment: @FranklinDattein My solution is only about the issue with Autowired. Maybe if I renamed test as integration test, it would make more scene to you. The validator will be called when you call the controller.

Comment: Your solution doesn't provide expected solution. It still gives NullPointerException when going to Repository and still not mocking it.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with JUnit4 and Mockito:

```java
@Import(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyCustomValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @MockBean
    private PersonRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void name_must_not_be_null() {
        // given
        when(repository.findByName(any())).thenReturn(Collection.emptyList());

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(null);

        // when
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);

        // then
        assertViolation(violations, "name", "Name must not be null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the validator stand alone and use reflection for inject the autowired attribute.

Constraint annotation:

```
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = EmailAlreadyExistsValidator.class)
    public @interface EmailAlreadyExists {
        String message() default "Email already exists in the database";

        Class<?>[] groups() default {};

        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }
```

Validator:

```
    public class EmailAlreadyExistsValidator implements 
    ConstraintValidator<EmailAlreadyExists, String> {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repository;

        @Override
        public void initialize(EmailAlreadyExists constraintAnnotation) {}

        public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            Optional<User> opUser = repository.findByEmail(email);
            return (opUser.isEmpty());
        }
    }
```

Unit Test (ReflectionTestUtils do the magic):

```
    public class EmailAlreadyExistsValidatorTest {

        @Mock
        private EmailAlreadyExists emailAlreadyExists;

        @Mock
        private ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext;

        @Mock
        private UserRepository repository;

        private EmailAlreadyExistsValidator validator;

        @BeforeEach
        public void beforeEach() {
            MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
            validator = new EmailAlreadyExistsValidator();
            validator.initialize(emailAlreadyExists);
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(validator, "repository", repository);
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("Given an user with existent email then validation must fail")
        public void isValid_existentPassword_mustFail() {

            final String existentEmail = "testuser@test.com";

            User savedUser = new User("1213443455",
                  "Test User",
                  existentEmail,
                  "12345",
                  new Date());
            Optional<User> opUser = Optional.of(savedUser);
            when(repository.findByEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(opUser);

            assertFalse(validator.isValid(existentEmail,constraintValidatorContext));

        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but I faced the same issue lately so I'll post how I solved the problem, as this could help other people.

The problem is basically that Hibernate's standard `Validator` implementation that you get by calling `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator()` does not know anything about Spring's application context so it cannot inject dependencies in your custom constraint validators.

In a Spring application the implementation of both the `Validator` and the `ValidatorFactory` interface is the class `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, which can delegate to the `ApplicationContext` to instantiate constraint validators with dependencies injected.

What you need to do is

1. Instantiate your constraint validators with their (mocked, I presume) dependencies
2. Create your own `ValidatorFactory` that holds all the constraint validators from bulletpoint 1
3. Instantiate your `Validator` from such factory

This is the custom validator factory

```
public class CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean {

    private final List<ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> customConstraintValidators;

    public CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean(List<ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> customConstraintValidators) {
        this.customConstraintValidators = customConstraintValidators;
        setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
        afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessConfiguration(Configuration<?> configuration) {
        super.postProcessConfiguration(configuration);
        ConstraintValidatorFactory defaultConstraintValidatorFactory =
                configuration.getDefaultConstraintValidatorFactory();
        configuration.constraintValidatorFactory(
                new ConstraintValidatorFactory() {
                    @Override
                    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
                        for (ConstraintValidator<?, ?> constraintValidator : customConstraintValidators) {
                            if (key.equals(constraintValidator.getClass())) //noinspection unchecked
                                return (T) constraintValidator;
                        }
                        return defaultConstraintValidatorFactory.getInstance(key);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
                        defaultConstraintValidatorFactory
                                .releaseInstance(instance);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

then in your test class you'd just do something like this:

```
class MyTestSuite {
    
    private final PersonRepository mockPersonRepository = Mockito.mock(PersonRepository.class);
    private final List<ConstraintValidator<?,?>> customConstraintValidators = 
            Collections.singletonList(new PersonNameMustBeUniqueValidator(mockPersonRepository));
    private final ValidatorFactory customValidatorFactory = 
            new CustomLocalValidatorFactoryBean(customConstraintValidators);
    private final Validator validator = customValidatorFactory.getValidator();

    @Test
    void myTestCase() {
        // mock the dependency: Mockito.when(mockPersonRepository...)
        Person p = new Person();
        //setters omitted
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = validator.validate(p);
        //assertions on the set of constraint violations
    }

}
```

Hope that helps. You can check out this post of mine for more details: https://codemadeclear.com/index.php/2021/01/26/how-to-mock-dependencies-when-unit-testing-custom-validators/

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented by overriding default Hibernate ConstraintValidatorFactory in my UnitTests

```
LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
localValidatorFactory.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
localValidatorFactory.setConstraintValidatorFactory(new ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl() {
        @Override
        public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> arg0) {
            T ret = super.getInstance(arg0);
            if (ret instanceof UniqueEmailValidator) {
                ((UniqueEmailValidator) ret).setUserService(userService);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    });
localValidatorFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: `ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.getInstance()` is `final` so this doesn't work. Not sure if that is a recent change.

Answer (score -3):

Spring Boot 2 allows to inject Bean in custom Validator without any fuss.The Spring framework automatically detects all classes which implement the  `ConstraintValidator` interface, instantiate them, and wire all dependencies.

I had Similar problem , this is how i have implemented.

**Step 1 Interface**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueFieldValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueField {

    String message() default "Duplicate Name";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Step 2 Validator**

```
public class UniqueFieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueField, Person> {
    @Autowired
    PersionList personRepository;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonRepository.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Person object, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        log.info("Validating Person for Duplicate {}",object);
        return personRepository.isPresent(object);

    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
@Component
@Validated
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    PersionList personRepository;

    public void addPerson(@UniqueField Person person) {
        personRepository.add(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP has already autowired the beans, the question is about how to test validators with autowired beans

Comment: downvoted - the question is about how to test validation and not how to implement it.