# Java.lang.nullpointer exception in junit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

My code for junit is

```
@Autowired
private ABC abc;

@Test
public void checkZonePresent() {
    assertThat(abc.getZoneList().size()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

SO, here I am getting error like java.lang.nullpointer exception

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714/how-to-write-junit-test-with-spring-autowire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance abc.getZoneList() is null. But also NPE  might if you didn't configured tests with spring (didn't ). It's difficult to say without code , show pls how you configured test class

zero step (in your case it helps , but in general you don't need to test it if you configured spring tests) :

> assertThat(abc ,is(notNullValue());

First you should check that  :

> assertThat(abc.getZoneList(),is(notNullValue());

and looks like ,**abc.getZoneList()** ,it's a problem
the next check should be

> assertThat(abc.getZoneList().size()).isEqualTo(1)

your test fail and there is no explanation why, but test should explains what's going wrong