# Using @Autowired in JUnit test class throws NullPointerException?

Tags: spring, junit, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

I am using autowiring (@Autowired) to inject dependencies in JUnit test class and am facing NullPointerException. I would like to know if autowiring is possible with/in JUnit test class. Else how should beans be injected in test classes. My code is as below -

**main class / client** - autowiring works as expected.

```
package com.example.demo;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import com.example.demo.services.IMessage;
import com.example.demo.services.SayWelcomeService;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo.services")
public class AutowireWithMultipleImplementationsApplication {
    @Autowired
    IMessage sayHelloService;

    @Autowired
    SayWelcomeService sayWelcome;

    @Autowired
    IMessage masterService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AutowireWithMultipleImplementationsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String message;
        message=masterService.message("George");
        System.out.println("message: \n" + message); 

        message=sayWelcome.message("george");
        System.out.println("message: " + message);      
    }
}
```

**Service interface and Implementation classes**
interface **IMessage**

```
package com.example.demo.services;
public interface IMessage {
    String message(String name);
}
```

Service **SayWelcomeService**

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SayWelcomeService implements IMessage {

    @Override
    public String message(String name) {
        return "Welcome Dear User - " + name ;
    }
}
```

service **SayHelloService**

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SayHelloService implements IMessage {

    @Override
    public String message(String name) {
        return "Hello Dear User - " + name ;
    }
}
```

master service calling other services. Autowiring works as expected.
**MasterService**

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MasterService implements IMessage  {

    @Autowired
    List<IMessage> listOfServices;

    @Autowired
    IMessage sayHelloService;

    @Autowired
    SayWelcomeService sayWelcome;

    @Override
    public String message(String name) {

        StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
        for(IMessage m: listOfServices)
        {
            messages.append(m.message(name));
            messages.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println(".....");
        System.out.println(sayHelloService.message(name));
        System.out.println(sayWelcome.message(name));

        return messages.toString();
    }    
}
```

Now the test class.
**SayWelcomeServiceTest**

```
package com.example.demo.tests;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.example.demo.services.SayWelcomeService;

public class SayWelcomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    SayWelcomeService sayWelcomeService;

    @Test
    public void testSayWelcomeMessage()
    {
        String message = sayWelcomeService.message("George");
        assertThat(message, equalTo("Welcome Dear User - George"));
    }    
}
```

**The problem is in the above class. @Autowired field(sayWelcomeService) is null. Why? How to solve this?**

Comment: please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714/how-to-write-junit-test-with-spring-autowire

Answer (score 6):

Two more annotations were necessary to wire the bean. They are mandatory, otherwise the test will fail.

Here is the working test class:

```
    @SpringBootTest
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class SayWelcomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private SayWelcomeService sayWelcomeService;

    @Test
    public void testSayWelcomeMessage()
    {
        String message = sayWelcomeService.message("George");
        assertThat(message, equalTo("Welcome Dear User - George"));
    }    
}
```

More information in [Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html):

> Spring Boot provides a @SpringBootTest annotation which can be used as
>   an alternative to the standard spring-test @ContextConfiguration
>   annotation when you need Spring Boot features. The annotation works by
>   creating the ApplicationContext used in your tests via
>   SpringApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing these annotations.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```