# mockito does not mock in the actual method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am mocking AuthService in the test below and setting authService.checkAuthority(any(UserAuthority.class))as "true". It is actually getting set but in the actual method(authService.checkAuthority(UserAuthority.COMMENT_ACCESS))  it is getting the value as false.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(ApplicationRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class TagsTest extends BaseWebTest {
    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;
    @Autowired
    private TagRepository repository;
    UserDetailsDto currentUser;
    @Autowired
    protected AuthService authService;
    @Autowired
    protected StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;
    @Autowired
    protected FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;
    protected static MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .dispatchOptions(true)
                .addFilters(filterChainProxy)
                .build();
        authService = Mockito.mock(AuthService.class);
        Mockito.reset(authService);

        when(authService.getCurrentUser()).then(i->(getCurrentUser()));            
        when(authService.checkAuthority(any(UserAuthority.class))).
                                        thenReturn(true);

        login(WORKFLOW_USER);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please confirm that AuthService and `checkAuthority` are both `public` and non-`final`? That's a common source of mocking trouble.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the reply. yes they are public and non-final

Answer (score 1):

Your specific issue might be solved just by removing this assignment:

```
authService = Mockito.mock(AuthService.class);
```

---

Your goal here is to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to create some of the dependencies in your graph, and use Mockito to *mock* other dependencies. However, as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21879476/1426891), anything marked with `@Autowired` in your test is created before the `@Before` method is run. This means that your call to replace `authService` above will only overwrite the field in your test; it won't adjust or change any of the other `@Autowired` fields, which have already been created, and which are already using the `authService` that you've bound in your Spring configuration.

#### Unit tests

If this is a unit test, and you're simply testing `TagsService` and `TagsRepository`, you might want to create those objects manually by calling their constructor with a combination of @Mock and @Autowired fields:

```
TagRepository repository = new TagRepository(/*mock*/ authService);
TagService tagService = new TagService(/*mock*/ authService, /*real*/ repository);
```

(Mockito provides a way to automate the creation of mocks using [@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html), but because it fails silently if it can't detect an appropriate mock, you might want to avoid that and call a constructor instead. [See this article for some good reasons and solutions.](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/))

Note that the above is only when you are working directly with objects in unit tests, not when you're relying on Spring's autowiring to inject objects deeper into your graph.

#### Integration tests

The test you posted looks like a web or integration test, so it looks like you want to replace the instances of `authService` with your mock *during their creation*. Typically this means making a change to the configuration XML or your ApplicationRunner, in order to instruct Spring to use a Mockito mock instead of your real AuthService. Though there are lots of ways to do this, you might want to favor using a Mockito-centric `FactoryBean` [as in this article](https://blog.jayway.com/2011/11/30/spring-integration-tests-part-i-creating-mock-objects/).

*But wait!* You may be using an ApplicationRunner that is already customized for Mockito. The line `authService = Mockito.mock(AuthService.class);` looks very much out-of-place for three reasons:

1. you are overwriting an `@Autowired` field, which rarely makes sense
2. you call `Mockito.mock` manually despite the existence of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`, which is generally preferred
3. you immediately `reset` the mock you create

This suggests to me that your `@Autowired` `authService` may *already* be a mock, and may *already* have stubbing, which is why you have a leftover `reset`. If so, then your problem isn't anything about Mockito, other than that you (or someone) have *overwritten* the field and stubbed your local copy instead of the one that Spring installs throughout your web test. That'd make it an easy fix: Delete your field reassignment and you may be good to go.

Comment: I am using Mockito to test the model and controller (controller -> model -> dao), so mocking the Dao only. I used Mock annotation or Mockito.mock(MyDao.class). I then use MockMvc.perform to call the controller, however the Dao (declared in the controller, autowired) is still going to the real Dao not the Mocked Dao. I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @KayKay I think that's a more substantial question than the comments would be good for. Please ask a new question, include enough surrounding code that an answerer could reproduce, and add a link to this question so answerers know you've seen it and are looking for ways to apply it. Good luck!