# Mockito - NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock my `AddressService` using JUnit with `Mockito`, the class under test looks a bit like this;

```java
    @Autowired
    private AddressDataManager addressDataManager;

    /**
     * Delegate AddressDataManager to add an individual Address object
     * @param address
     * @return Address object
     */
    public Address addAddress(Address address) {
        return this.addressDataManager.addAddress(address);
    }
```

Which then calls a JPA repository;

```java
     /**
     * Create a new Address
     * 
     * @param address
     * @return JSON representation of an Address object
     */
    public Address addAddress(Address address) {
        addressRepo.save(address);
        return address;
    }
```

This issue is that I am getting a `NullPointerException`, when trying to create an Address result object using `addAddress`, which invokes the `save()` repository method call in my `addressService` class. It seems to be not returning the address object when I send an address object to it.

I have tried to;

- create a constructor with the `AddressRepository` and `AddressDataManager` in `AddressManager`
- Strangely, it works fine when I remove the `@Mock` `addressRepository` and `AddressDataManager` from the class and instead use `AddressManager` as the `@Mock` (instead of `@InjectMocks`). But I'm not sure that is the correct approach as some methods in `AddressManager` directly use the `AddressRepository`, so it should also create a NPE.

My `Mockito` test code:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class AddressServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AddressRepository addressRepo;

    @Mock
    private AddressDataManager addressDataManager;

    @InjectMocks
    private AddressManager addressService;

    public Address createTestData() {
        /** Create an Address **/
        Address mockAddress = new Address();
        /** Set fields **/
        mockAddress.setId((long) 1);
        mockAddress.setStreet("A Street");
        // ...
        return mockAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Test the addressService addAddress and addessRepo save method
     */
    @Test
    public void addAddressTest() {
        Address mockAddress = createTestData();
        /** Test the return type of save is indeed `Address` **/
        when(addressRepo.save(mockAddress)).thenReturn(mockAddress);    
        /** Create a returning result object to test addAddress method return **/
        Address addResult = addressService.addAddress(mockAddress); // NullPointerException here
        /** Check values are equal to address object **/
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(1), addResult.getId());
        assertEquals("A Street", addResult.getStreet());
        // ...
        /** Verify that addressRepo save was called once using Mockito **/
        verify(addressRepo, times(1)).save(addResult); 
        verify(addressService, times(1)).addAddress(addResult);
    }
```

I feel like I am close, maybe I have the wrong tag over the wrong class? As I said, it worked well when I just used it like so;

```java
@Mock
private AddressManager addressService;

/** Test the return type of addAddress is indeed `Address` **/
when(addressService.addAddress(mockAddress)).thenReturn(mockAddress);   
/** Verify that addressService addAddress was called once using Mockito **/
verify(addressService , times(1)).addAddress(addResult);
```

Comment: have you checked on which field you have the NPE?

Comment: In case you are using spring, you know that spring has its own way of doing unit testing, build around its DI mechanism? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714/how-to-write-junit-test-with-spring-autowire for example.

Comment: @Stultuske yes, it's the addResult. I added a comment next to it, indicating it has a NullPointerException

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC I prefer to use Mockito, as I need to test the service layer to not update database tables when testing.

Comment: If you mock the `addressDataManager`, mocking the `addressRepo` (which seems to be a dependency of the `addressDataManager`) should not be necessary. Mocking the `addressService` does not help you, as mocking the class under test is not something you should do.

Comment: If you get a `NPE` it implies that your mock for `addressDataManager` is not properly injected (or can not be mocked). How does you constructor for your `AddressManager` look like? Maybe you can provide an example that includes these classes.