# Spring Boot - how to initialize class from a dependent module with injected dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have two Maven projects A and B, where project B is nested in project A. The structure looks like the following:

```
Project A:
    src/test/java:
        MyTest.java
    Project B:
        src/test/java:
            MyNewTest.java
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

My goal is to let MyNewTest.java act as a wrapper of MyTest.java, and be able to invoke the test methods declared in MyTest.java from MyNewTest.java. MyTest has some injected dependencies.

My question is: how to initialize MyTest in MyNewTest to make sure that all the dependencies of MyTest are injected properly?

MyTest looks like the following:

```
public class MyTest {
    
    @Autowired
    Service service; 

    @Autowired
    TestUtil util;

    Info info;
    
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        info = service.getStuff();
    }

    @Test
    public test1() {
        service.getMoreStuff();
        // more code omitted
    }
     
}
```

I have tried adding @Component to MyTest, and then in MyNewTest.java, use @Autowired like the following:

```
public class MyNewTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyTest baseTest;

    @Test
    public void runTest() {
        // run the test in MyTest.java
        baseTest.test1();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work - baseTest is null. I also tried initializing MyTest by calling its default constructor, but the dependencies failed to be injected as expected. Can anyone suggest a proper way to initialize MyTest.java so that all its dependencies are injected as well? Thanks

Comment: Tough to diagnose without more info. One minor point, a small typo in your code - the first class is MyTest right? not MyNewTest. That aside one clue is that if an autowired field is null after startup then the instance that contains that field is not being included in the Spring application context, as startup would fail with an error along the lines of expected a bean of type MyTest. So, either Spring isn't creating an instance of MyNewTest (is its package in scope of ComponentScan?) or you have a reference to an instance that isn't the one in the applicationcontext

Comment: How do you know it is null? NullPointerException or debugging? And when your test starts do you see Spring Boot firing up? Just a couple of thoughts on what other clues may be available

Comment: Actually, if these are Test classes that need to run with a Spring Boot context I think you'd need to annotate the classes as SpringBootTest

Comment: @Chris Thank you Chris. Yes sorry the first class is MyTest, I edited. I found it's null from both debugging and the NullPointerException. Could you elaborate on ComponentScan? Should I add ComponentScan to MyNewTest and specify the package of MyTest?

Comment: You have a couple of issues here, first test classes aren't spring beans and thus you cannot auto wire them, second test classes aren't part of the artifact created for a project (so they aren't there). Also generally creating dependent tests like this is generally a really bad idea.

Comment: Important points here - if the intention is to create unit tests then do not involve Spring - that's a benefit of dependency injection, you can test classes in isolation as suggested in the answer and instantiate your instances with mocks. If you are aiming for integration tests then as above, you need to separate your tests from your Spring application, then your test can be run in a Spring application context as in the second option of the answer, mocking beans if necessary with MockBean annotations - you need to read up if this is what you want - https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: (above relates to testing web but explains main ideas. Also worth looking at Baeldung's guide - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing but also dig out the actual Spring documentation on integration testing)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your test is the @Autowired annotations as the Spring wiring isn't being triggered. There are two different paths you can take to fix this.

The first option is to manually instantiate `baseTest` in `MyNewTest` at which point it will no longer be null. However, tests will still fail because your two @Autowired dependencies will be null. You can either add setters or inject them via your constructor. Note- these classes should be mocked if you are performing Unit Tests. Here's how it would look if you chose to add these classes via the constructor -

```
     private Service service;
     private TestUtil util;
     private MyTest baseTest;

     @BeforeEach
     void setUp() {
          service = mock(Service.class);
          util = mock(TestUtil.class);
          baseTest = new MyTest(service, util);
     }
```

The second option is to add configuration to your Test class to support the Spring wiring. I am not familiar with taking this route as I always choose the first option when possible. There are multiple ways to add the Spring wiring but the easiest is-

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyNewTest {
```

However, this does not cover all use cases so you may need more specific configurations. You can find some of the possible options here - [How to write JUnit test with Spring Autowire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714/how-to-write-junit-test-with-spring-autowire)

Edit- As I immediately recognized a problem, I didn't read the rest very carefully and I missed that these were Test classes you were trying to wire together. I am not sure if this is possible.

Only Spring beans can be @Autowired so the first step would be to attempt to add configuration to make your Test class into a Spring bean. I've never heard of this being done before but it would be easy to try. If not, you can get around this problem by using the first option.

The second problem is that tests are not included in the artifact. I'd imagine you could circumvent this issue by mixing your Test classes in with your regular classes but this is considered a bad practice. I've never heard of tests being dependent on other tests but I'd guess this is also a bad practice. What's the reason for wanting to create your Tests this way?