# Springboot test using ConfigurationProperties to fill Map

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have a generic class that i used to load some keys from my application yaml file ,here's my yaml file :

```
errabi.security:
  keyStores:
      jwt:
        type: JKS
        location: classpath:keystore.jks
        keyStorePassword: password # to be encrypted
        keyPassword: password # to be encrypted
        keyAlias: errabi
      jwe:
        type: JKS
        location: classpath:keystore.jks
        keyStorePassword: password # to be encrypted
        keyPassword: password # to be encrypted
        keyAlias: errabi
```

And here's the class the I use to load values based on some keys :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "errabi.security")
public class KeyStoreConfig {

    private Map<String, KeyStoreConfig.KeyStoreConfiguration> keyStores;

    public Map<String, KeyStoreConfiguration> getKeyStores() {
        return keyStores;
    }

    public void setKeyStores(Map<String, KeyStoreConfiguration> keyStores) {
        this.keyStores = keyStores;
    }

    public static class KeyStoreConfiguration {
          private String type;
          private String location;
          private char [] keyStorePassword;
          private char [] keyPassword;
          private String keyAlias;
          // getters and setters
}
}
```

In my application when i call the method KeyStoreConfig.getKeyStores() i get the map with the key values , but in my test i still not able to inject the bean `KeyStoreConfig`

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = KeyStoreConfig.class)
class JWEUtilTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    private KeyStoreConfig keyStoreConfig;
    
    // in the debug mode the KeyStoreConfig.getKeyStores() return a null instead of a map with keyvalues
}
```

during my test i get a `NullPointerException` when i debug i see that the `KeyStoreConfig.getKeyStores()` return a null instead of a map with keyvalues
did i miss something in my configuration ? thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you're using the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation over the `@SpringBootTest`, it seems that some Spring Boot features are disabled, like loading of external properties specified in the `application.properties` or `application.yaml`.

To enable it manually you should add to your test class: `@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeyStoreConfig.class)`.

**Some helpful links about spring boot testing:**

[Spring Boot Testing @ConfigurationProperties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-configurationproperties)

[@SpringBootTest vs @ContextConfiguration vs @Import in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712707/springboottest-vs-contextconfiguration-vs-import-in-spring-boot-unit-test)

I also found [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2019/02/difference-between-contextconfiguration-and-springapplicationConfiguration-annotations-in-spring-boot-testing.html#axzz77VBPR5Dt) article interesting, it's about difference between `@ContextConfiguration` and [`@SpringApplicationConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html), which is deprecated as of 1.4 spring boot version in favor of `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Thanks the probleme was in the application.yml name i have a wrong name "applicationt.yml" , @EnableConfigurationProperties(KeyStoreConfig.class) solve the probleme