# Spring Boot: In Service Unit Test the autowired Service object is NULL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I need to write a unit test for a Service class's method. That Service class has an inner DAO object which I'm mocking. However, the Service itself is **not** mocked because that's what I actually need to execute and test.

I'm getting the error that the Service is NULL, even though it's auto-wired, and `@ContextConfiguration` specifies its implementation class.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  Cannot invoke "app.Ar11ApplicationService.process()" because "this.ar11ApplicationService" is null
```

Unit Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Ar11ApplicationServiceImpl.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Ar11ApplicationServiceTest {
    
    // The inner DAO is mocked - will return some test collections set up in setUp()
    @Mock
    private Ar11ApplicationDAO ar11ApplicationDAO;
    
    @Autowired
    private Ar11ApplicationService ar11ApplicationService;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
       //set up... - set up mock objects, test collections, etc.
    }

    @Test
    void testService_HappyPath() {
       // this is the actual test where I execute the Service class's method
       ar11ApplicationService.process();
    }
```

Note that I don't have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation because that would cause the whole app to run. Instead, I'm using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to just run my specific Service unit test.

Comment: Try `@InjectMocks`.

Comment: Yup that worked! `@InjectMocks` instead of `Autowired` is the solution. thanks

Comment: You actually hard-code your service implementation `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Ar11ApplicationServiceImpl.class)`, so in this case I don't see much profit from autowiring Ar11ApplicationService and not just create Ar11ApplicationServiceImpl with constructor, injecting your dao mock.

Comment: To take this one step further, since this is a test that only uses mocks, you don't need the `@ContextConfiguration` or the `@ExtendWith`, and you can replace `@RunWith...` with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: While testing your Service layer you don't even need to load the context. Just test it as a regular class following the mockito way. Take a look here fore more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712707/springboottest-vs-contextconfiguration-vs-import-in-spring-boot-unit-test/70601994#70601994